# SQL sum 77 rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I need to sum 77 rows into the one revenue. I tried the sum functions, but nothing works. I don't know if it's even possible to sum 77 rows.

```sql
select  IntId,ValueInDefaultPriceUnit,Test=0,DocumentTypeId,Enabled=1,DepartmentId,BalanceId,Date,StateId, sum(ValueInDefaultPriceUnit) over (partition by IntId) as revenue
from _EPOS_DocumentPayments as dp inner join _EPOS_Documents as d on d.ID = dp.ID
where BalanceId between 62 and 64
AND StateId between 2 and 4
AND DocumentTypeId = 4
AND DepartmentId = 4
```

I expect the last revenue column will be sum of the ValueInDefaultPriceUnit, but it only overwrites the data.

Comment: Can you give a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's hard to read badly formatted code, but, after cleaning it up a bit, it looks like it should work. So, in order for us to reproduce the problem, you need to post the source data.

Comment: i cant really share the data with u bc its data from one company. But all u need to know i need to sum all the 77 rows ValueInDefaultPriceUnit to the one number of all the rows

Comment: OK. Then your code should be working. Your move. Instead of posting actual source data, post some generic data that reproduces the error. Refer to @Ineffable21's first comment about posting reproducible examples.

Comment: What is the relationship between the `_EPOS_DocumentPayments` and `_EPOS_Documents` tables? Are you sure that your join condition is correct? The `d.ID = dp.ID` join condition implies a 1-to-1 relationship (assuming some customary naming conventions). If the true relationship is 1-to-many or many-to-one, you need to look for the foreign key constraint and join using those columns. Might be something like `d.ID = dp.Document_ID` or `d.DocumentPayment_ID = dp.ID`. And yes, SQL Server can sum 77 rows without even breaking a sweat.